# Inserting a slide break within a code chunk in rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, ioslides

I am preparing some slides using Rmarkdown (ioslides_presentation) and I was wondering if it is possible to force a slide break within a chunk of code.

I saw some similar questions for pdf, but I cannot make those solutions work in the case of HTML slides.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

~1.5 years later, I came here looking for an answer to the same question. For future people in the same situation:

I managed to solve it with

```
knitr::asis_output("\n\n---\n\n")
```

at the position were I wanted to force a new slide.