# How can I split R/Stan code chunks across two slides (quarto + revealjs)?

Tags: r, reveal.js, stan, quarto

I have some large code chunks that exceed the length of one slide.  I want the code to easily split across two slides.  This comes up when I want to display a large function that I can't easily split across two R code chunks. I also regularly print my slides to pdf for later annotation, so the scrollable code isn't helpful.

Is there any straightfoward way to do this?

I tried adding something like `knitr::asis_output("\n\n---\n\n")` into an R code chunk to manually add the slide break, following [Inserting a slide break within a code chunk in rmarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60393280/inserting-a-slide-break-within-a-code-chunk-in-rmarkdown)

but this didn't work.

Comment: Instead, may be you can try for vertical scrolling?!

Comment: Maybe try ```` knitr::asis::output("\n```\n\n---\n\n```{.r}\n") ````. Edit: ugh, StackOverflow doesn't implement the CommonMark spec correctly. There are three backticks on each side surrounding the `\n\n---\n\n`.